# How do I seperate two faces by shared vertices?

Tags: vertices, faces

I want to split two faces exactly where the vertices lay as seen below. How can I do this?

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Select the 2 vertices you want to split and press <kbd>v</kbd> to **[Rip](https://www.blender.org/manual/modeling/meshes/editing/vertices.html?highlight=rip#rip)** the edge. You'll have a result like that

[image]

[image]

(from the [blender manual](https://www.blender.org/manual/contents.html))

> Rip creates a “hole” into a mesh by making a copy of selected vertices and edges, still linked to the neighbor non-selected vertices, so that the new edges are borders of the faces on one side, and the old ones, borders of the faces of the other side of the rip.