# How do I mark a seam at an edge shared by 3 faces as a seam for only two of those faces?

Tags: uv, uv-image-editor

I've got a house that needs a seam where the four outer walls meet the roof. If I place a seam where I need it, it separates the roof directly above the house from the overhang, which is unwanted. 
Here's a picture. The highlighted edge is one of the problematic seams
[image] 
So, how do I fix this?

Comment: Not sure what exactly is the problem, what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Never use "edges shared by 3 faces", that is generally considered a bad modelling practice, creating non-manifold meshes that will among other things lead to problems like the one you just encountered. Why not just separate those edges?

Comment: This might help [Rip Verts](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/49909/how-do-i-seperate-two-faces-by-shared-vertices/49910#49910)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the roof has no thickness - so anything you do with one side of it (add creases, set material, etc) affects the other. You need to give the roof a thickness so that it has a proper 'inside' and 'outside' - this is referred to as being 'manifold'. There are various ways of achieving this but the simplest is to go into Edit mode (<kbd>Tab</kbd>), select all the faces making up the roof, and hit <kbd>E</kbd> to Extrude, and then move the newly generated faces up to form the solid roof (hit <kbd>Z</kbd> to constrain movement to the Z-axis then move the mouse up).

Answer (score 0):

It is possible you could just alter the topology so that the roof does not share an edge with the walls.

Probably the quickest way to do this would be to select all the roof polygons and use <kbd>p</kbd> to Separate the mesh by selection.  Then go into Object mode, select both objects, and <kbd>Ctrl-j</kbd> to join the separated objects back into a single mesh.

The alternative of using Mesh > Edge > Edge Split would be more complicated since you want the wall polygons to share edges.  I'm not sure what operator you could use to reunify the edges of only the wall.  A Remove Doubles would glue the roof back to the walls again.